# How to use Jquery load() in Play Framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery, playframework

I tried to load an html page to a div when button click event happens.

```
function loadPage(page){ 
    if (page == "publications"){ 
        $( "#container" ).load("publications.scala.html");
        //$( "#container" ).load("app/views/publications.scala.html"); // also not work
        //$( "#container" ).load("../app/views/publications.scala.html"); // also not work
    } 
}
```

the `publications.scala.html`is in my app/views folder

So when I tried it will say at the console `404 (Not Found)` for the file.

How can I make this work. Is there any specific way to do this in Play Framework.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

**Routes**

```
GET     /show                          controllers.Application.show()
```

**Controller**

```
public static Result show(){
        return ok(views.html.publications.render());
    }
```

**Script**

```
$( "#container" ).load("/show");
```